# why isnull() and .isNull in Pyspark 1.6 producing different results?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i am using Spark 1.6 with Python 2.7 and have 2 simple Pyspark dataframes-

```
>>> df.show()
+-----------+-------------------+
|cust_agt_id|          source_id|
+-----------+-------------------+
|       abcd|                  1|
|        abc|                  1|
|        bcd|                  1|
+-----------+-------------------+
>>> cache.show()
+-----------+---------+-------+
|cust_agt_id|source_id|inCache|
+-----------+---------+-------+
|      abcd1|        1|      1|
|        abc|        1|      1|
|       bcd1|        1|      1|
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

I am just joining these 2 dataframes (left join)

```
>>> joinColumns=['cust_agt_id','source_id']

>>> df.join(cache,joinColumns,"left").filter(isnull(cache['inCache'])).show()
+-----------+---------+-------+
|cust_agt_id|source_id|inCache|
+-----------+---------+-------+
+-----------+---------+-------+

>>> df.join(cache,joinColumns,"left").filter(col("inCache").isNull()).show()
+-----------+---------+-------+
|cust_agt_id|source_id|inCache|
+-----------+---------+-------+
|       abcd|        1|   null|
|        bcd|        1|   null|
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

Why are these two null check conditions behaving differently. I get the correct result with 2nd one- "filter(col("inCache").isNull())"

Thanks

Sid

Comment: What is `isnull`? Show the import used. You may think you're using [`pyspark.sql.functions.isNull()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull) (Notice the capital N) but I have a feeling you're actually using [`pandas.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html).

Comment: Please refer it, it has both of these - http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html